# Python: How to use variables across modules

Tags: python, module, global-variables, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to figure out how to use variables and setups across modules.

Am I right when I think it's smart to keep separate functions of a program in separate modules?

I have a main program module called `main.py` and in it I have this:

```
# Sets GPIO's to HIGH = Relays OFF
try:
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
except RuntimeError:
    Print("Error importing RPi.GPIO!!")

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
# GPIO16 is relay1
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
# GPIO11 is relay2
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
```

I then `import` a module (in that module I have a function called `Relay`)
and try to use the function with `module1.Relay(1,1)`

But the function in `module1` needs the `GPIO` from the main.py to Work. How do I go about with this?
I really don't want the `GPIO` setting part in the `module1`, I don't want it to be run every time I run the `module1.Relay(1,1)` call..

What is best practice for working across modules? (I'm making a controller for my home's heat system.)

Comment: You can `import RPi.GPIO as GPIO` in module1. It won't actually be imported more than once, but you will have access to the functions/namespace. Also, nothing wrong with putting the functions in your main.py if it's not unwieldy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about keeping separate functionality of your application in different modules - it absolutely makes sense to group your code in logically related units. That's not always trivial though, and forces you to clearly think about that depends on what, and separation of concerns. What you've come across here is called a **circular import**.

There's two obvious ways to resolve circular imports:

- **Extract** the thing that's shared by more than one module, and put it in its separate module. In your case that's the `GPIO` including its initialization.
- Don't import the thing that's shared in every module, but instead import it once and pass it as an **argument** to other things that need it.

### Extracting it into its own module

Extracting the `GPIO` initialization into it's own module could look like this:

**main.py**

```
from gpio import GPIO
import module1

print "main: %s" % GPIO.__name__
# Do stuff wth GPIO

module1.Relay()
```

**gpio.py**

```
# Sets GPIO's to HIGH = Relays OFF
try:
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
except RuntimeError:
    print("Error importing RPi.GPIO!!")

print "Setting up GPIO"
GPIO.state = 'initialized'
print "Done setting up"
```

**module1.py**

```
from gpio import GPIO

def Relay():
    print "Relay: %s" % GPIO.__name__
    # Do stuff with GPIO
```

Output when running `main.py`:

```
Setting up GPIO
Done setting up
main: RPi.GPIO
Relay: RPi.GPIO
```

As you can see, the GPIO initialization in the global scope of the `gpio.py` module is run only once, on the first occasion the module is imported anywhere.

### Passing as an argument

The other option, importing GPIO once and passing as an argument could look like this:

**main.py**

```
# Sets GPIO's to HIGH = Relays OFF
try:
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
except RuntimeError:
    print("Error importing RPi.GPIO!!")

print "Setting up GPIO"
GPIO.state = 'initialized'
print "Done setting up"

import module1

print "main: %s" % GPIO.__name__
# Do stuff wth GPIO

module1.Relay(GPIO)
```

**module1.py**

```
def Relay(gpio):
    print "Relay: %s" % gpio.__name__
    # Do stuff with GPIO
```

Both are valid ways in your case, in my opinion. I personally would prefer to have the initialization in a central `gpio.py` module and then import from there, but that's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically there should be no problem just importing the GPIO from the other module. Check this example for instance:

**gpio.py**

```
# Dummy GPIO module

some_value = 5

def set_value(new_value):
    global some_value
    some_value = new_value

def get_value():
    return some_value
```

**module1.py**

```
import gpio

def Relay(a, b):
    print "module1.Relay:", gpio.get_value()
```

**main.py**

```
import gpio

gpio.set_value(1337)

import module1

module1.Relay(1,1) # Prints the new value (1337)
```